# Create Qdate object from int or string

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyside

I want to make a specific date like `4-5-2016` (`string` or `int`) and convert it into a valid object that QDate can interact with.

Is there a way to convert or create a QDate from a string or an int in `PySide`?

Comment: What do you mean by int? `4-5-2016` is not an int.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use `QDate.fromString()` or `QDate.fromJulianDay()`

Example:

```
d = QDate.fromString("4-5-2015", "d-M-yyyy")
```

See the [QDate documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdate.html)